# Why is Code First Entity Framework generating a foreign key?

Tags: mapping, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

So I've got...

```
public class User
{
   public int ManagerId { get; set; }
   public Manager Manager { get; set; }
}

public class Manager
{
   public User User { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
.HasOptional(x => x.Manager)
.WithOptionalDependent(x => x.User);
```

Thus a user has an optional Manager and a Manager may or may not have a User. This works in that Manager doesn't have a foreign key to a User but a User has a nullable foreign key to a Manager. But its generating the foreign key and treating ManagerId as a regular property. How do I fix this?

Cheers, Ian.

Comment: Deleted my answer because it was wrong. I didn't consider that it's one-to-one relation which is another story as explained in Ladislav's answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is one-to-one relation. It works only if the foreign key is built on top of primary key. You need something like this:

```
public class User
{
   [Key, ForeingKey("Manager")]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public Manager Manager { get; set; }
}

public class Manager
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public User User { get; set; }
}
```

If manager has a user, user must have the same PK value as manager. You will not be able to define such relation optional on both sides because it would violate FK. In fluent mapping you should do something like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Manager>()
            .HasOptional(m => m.User)
            .WithRequired(u => u.Manager);
```